# Append div inside of td and set the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have multiple tables that I need to populate. I use jQuery to loop through table cells. If table cell has `data-text` attribute I need to append `div` element. Div element will allow cell to have scroll bar vertical. This way table won't expend if text is too long.

Here is example of my code:

```
$('#'+tabID+' table tr td').each(function(){
  elementID = $(this).prop('id').toUpperCase();
  value = $.trim(decodeURIComponent(obj.DATA[elementID]['value']));

  if($(this).attr('data-text')) {
    $(this).append('<div class="hm_textScroll">'+value+'</div>');
  } else {
    $(this).text(value).css({'color':'blue','font-weight':'bold'});
  }
});
```

Code above will append `div` element and set the value but the problem is that if I move to a different table and come back again one more div will append. That creates duplicate. I'm not sure what is the best way to prevent that? Or if there is a better way to work around this. If anyone have suggestions please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```
$('#' + tabID + ' table tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    elementID = $(this).prop('id').toUpperCase();
    value = $.trim(decodeURIComponent(obj.DATA[elementID]['value']));

    if(typeof $(this).attr('data-text') != 'undefined') {
      if($(this).find('div.hm_textScroll').length > 0){
        $(this).find('div.hm_textScroll').text(value);
       } else {
        $(this).append(`<div class="hm_textScroll">${value}</div>`);
       }       
    } else {
      $(this).text(value).css({'color':'blue','font-weight':'bold'});
    }
  });
});
```

First loop through each `tr` then loop through each `td`.

For check the `data-attribute`, use `typeof $(this).attr('data-text') != 'undefined`

In the if statement (true condition) I've used backtick `ES6` for appending div container.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This solution won't prevent multiple append. Every time I run this loop new div element will be appended inside of td cell.

Comment: @espresso_coffee .I've updated the answer, have a look. An example solution https://jsfiddle.net/zb8ntoL9/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would have to additionally check whether a `<div class="hm_textScroll"></div>` already exists in the `<td>`.

One possible solution using vanilla javascript would be this:

```
const tableElement = document.querySelectorAll('#'+tabID+'table tr td');
tableElement.forEach(td => {
  if (td.hasAttribute("data-text")) {
    if (!td.querySelector(".hm_textScroll")) {
      td.innerHTML='<divclass="hm_textScroll">'+value+'</div>'
    }
  }
});
```